# Unable to get Primary Key as a model instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models `Role` and `User`.

When use the object's `get()` method with the `Role` model like this -

```
role= Role.objects.get(pk=1)
```

It returns `id` as an **instance** of `Role` like this -

```
<Role: Role object (2)>
```

But when I do the same thing with `User` model like this -

```
user= User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

It returns an `email` as an **instance** of `User` model like this -

```
<User: pqw109@inc.com>
```

How can I make `User` model return an `id` as an instance, exactly like Role model.

What exactly will I have to do to achieve this -

```
<User: User object (2)>
```

Comment: The reason this happens is because the have made an override of `__str__` and `__repr__`. This is just how it prints the item. All columns are loaded from the database, but not all are presented.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did not do any override of `__str__` and `__repr__` in my models. Could you tell me how to get `<User: User object (2)>` from `User` model.

Comment: It will help when you post the models.py for user and role. Besides that, WillemVanOnsem is correct saying that the returned object in both cases contains all model fields. Try it with print(user.pk)

Comment: @imolitor `print(user.pk)` will just return an integer value like `2`. What I need is an object of `User` model which is `<User: User object (2)>`

Comment: disregarding the presentation of the object as 'id' or 'email', you'll always do have  the whole object of which you could access any field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `User` model was returning user instance which used the **email** as the string representation. To change the string representation, I have overridden the default `__str__()` method on the `User` model to return `str(self.id)`.

Here is how it can be done -

```
def __str__(self):
    """Return string representation of user"""
    return 'User Object ({})'.format(self.id)
```